# Dynamic Request per minute in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

When we have a constant request per minute we can use timer to control throughput, but let's assume we have a CSV containing a number of requests every minute (dynamic throughput per minute) like:

| timestamp | Num. Of. Request|
| ..01:01:00| 9 |
| ..01:02:00| 3 |
| ..01:03:00| 23|
| ..01:04:00| 5 |

I tried to use [**constant throughput timer** with beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) but with handy input value not from csv.

Is there any good way to simulate this in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all are you aware of [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Throughput-Shaping-Timer) in general and [`load_profile`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) special property in particular?

---

If you want to continue with your "CSV" approach here is how it could be implemented: you can read the file in Groovy in separate Thread Group and overwrite the property value

"Handy" shorthands:

- `new File('path-to-your-file.csv').readLines().get('x')` - read line number `x` from the `test.csv` file
- `vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long` - get [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of the time when the test was started
- `props.put('throughput', some-value-from-CSV-here)` - write the value from CSV into `throughput` JMeter property

Then you can use `${__P(throghput,)}` function in the Constant Throughput Timer

More information:

- [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
- [Pre-Defined Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: when should change the value for the throughput variable?